# how to get list of branches that is squash merged to another remote

Tags: git, github

### Disclaimer:

Searched many questions through stackoverflow, but could only find solutions related to single repository, could not find questions related to forks (or in other words, multiple remotes)

### How to reproduce:

1. there's an `upstream` repository. its default branch is `main`.
2. fork it into `origin` repository.
3. make `main` branch track `upstream/main` in order to make fetching newest commit easier.
4. create a new branch `origin/foo`, make multiple commits (e.g: `a`, `b`, `c`)
5. make a Pull Request to `upstream`, and it gets squash merged as `abc`.

### Now the question is:

Would there be any way to get a list of local branches (in this question, `origin/foo`) that is squash merged to `upstream`?

Comment: in any branch of `upstream` or in `upstream/main` ?

Comment: @Ôrel for `upstream/main`, since PR from fork mostly targets upstream's default branch.

Comment: Whats wrong with `git branch --merged upstream/main` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it only shows my `main` and nothing else, with/without `upstream/main` part.

Comment: You ask for local branch so this is normal to not have remote (upstream) branch. Add `-a` if you want the remote branch

Comment: edited question, since I think the reason it did not work for me was because i use squash merge. in this case I only get `main`, `remotes/origin/main`, and `remotes/upstream/main` despite there's 6 squash-merged branches in the local.

Answer (score 1):

A squash merge is not a real merge. It is a new commit that has no notion of its merged branch. There is no way to get this information with Git. (Maybe there is with GitHub, but Git does not have this information. By choosing squash-merge you are saying: "forget about the branches, and only create a commit with the code changes")